# Wordpress too long waiting time in request domain

Tags: wordpress, http, dns, httpresponse, pagespeed

I have a wordpress website but it's to slow due to domain waiting time. I run some test on it and get this response. What can i do or try to fix this meaningless waiting...

Here this is waterfall

[image: waterfall]

And this is the details about first query

[image]

i tried to disabling plugins but result is still the same. How can i fix this?